# JavaScript Code for URL Opener

Tags: javascript, url

I am creating a Multiple URL Opener in JavaScript which open all the URLs in new tabs from the text area. This is working fine and it open all the URLs in new tab but the problem is when a user puts new list in the text area, the new URLs replace the old URLs i.e. The new URLs opens in the same tabs the old one opened replacing the old websites.

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function OpenURL(txid) {

    var lines;
    var TA = document.getElementById(txid).value;
    if(document.all) { // IE
        lines = TA.split("\r\n");

    }
    else { //Mozilla
        lines = TA.split("\n");
    }
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {



    if(/^([a-z]([a-z]|\d|\+|-|\.)*):(\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-     \uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?((\[(|(v[\da-f]{1,}\.(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~)|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)+))\])|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(:\d*)?)(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*|(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)){0})(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(lines[i])) {

    if(lines[i]!=''){
        window.open(lines[i], 'example' + i);
         }
    } else {

   if(lines[i]!=''){
         var openurl="http://"+lines[i];
       window.open(openurl, 'example' + i);
      }
    }

    }
 }
-->
</script>
```

I am not good in JavaScript. Please help me to correct the code.

Any help will be greatly appriciated..

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same window names. Define some variable 'C' outside the OpenURL function and change window.open to use it.

```
var C = 1;
function OpenURL( txtid ) {
    ...
    window.open(openurl, 'example' + (C++))
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to create a Javascript that will enable open links in new tab.. a google search on this question brought this [post](http://w3guy.com/build-bulk-url-opener-tool/)
That might be of help.